# Max-Width vs. Min-Width

Tags: css, media-queries, zurb-foundation

Most of the tutorials I'm reading on using Media Queries are demonstrating the use of `min-width`, but I'm rarely seeing people using `max-width`.

Is this some sort of design trend, or pattern, why people are using `min-width` over `max-width`?

For example, I'm designing a site starting from mobile, working up to the desktop. I am using Foundation 4, but using media queries to remove various elements on the page and re-position the source order.

One thing I am facing is a custom navigation for any device whose width is 360px or less. I want them to have a vertical navigation, rather than an inline horizontal. So my idea was to use `max-width` to target these devices.

Should I be using `min-width` instead if I am designing mobile first? I.e. all the default styles are for mobile, and thus using `min-width` to progressively enhance the layout?

Comment: I think it depends on how much CSS is involved. If you only have few additional lines of CSS to make that navigation appear vertically, you can use `max-width` without worrying about it.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

It really depends on how your stylesheet works. For example:

```
@media screen and (min-width:100px) {
    body { font-weight:bold; }
}

@media screen and (min-width:200px) {
    body { color:#555; }
}
```

The above two media queries would make the `body` font bold if the screen is greater than or equal to 100px, but *also* make the color `#555` if it's greater than or equal to 200px;

Another example:

```
@media screen and (max-width:100px) {
    body { font-weight:bold; }
}

@media screen and (max-width:200px) {
    body { color:#555; }
}
```

Unlike the first example, this makes the `body` font bold and color `#555` only if the screen width is between 0 and 100px. If it's between 0px and 200px it will be color `#555`.

The beauty of media queries is that you can combine these statements:

```
@media screen and (min-width:100px) and (max-width:200px) {
    body { font-weight:bold; color:#555; }
}
```

In this example you are only targeting devices with a width between 100px and 200px - nothing more, nothing less.

In short, if you want your styles to *leak* out of media queries you'd use either `min-width` *or* `max-width`, but if you're wanting to affect a very specific criteria you can just combine the two.

Comment: very nice description sir. i easy understand..thanks

Comment: @Ryan no worries. I've deleted my comments now. :)

Comment: @Drenai, you are absolutely right

Answer (score 137):

**2 Part Answer**

**Part 1: To answer "why people are using min-width over max-width?":**

It has to do with design flow. Typically, with min-width patterns, you're designing mobile-first. With max-width patterns, you're design desktop-first.

Going mobile-first with min-width, the default style is the mobile style. Queries after that then target progressively larger screens.

```
body {
    /* default styles here, 
       targets mobile first */
}

@media screen and (min-width:480px) {
    /* style changes when the screen gets larger */
}

@media screen and (min-width:800px) {
        /* And even larger */
    }
```

Conversely, using max-width, is desktop-first then adds queries to make styles mobile-friendly

```
body {
        /* default styles here, 
           targets desktops first */
    }

@media screen and (max-width:800px) {
    /* style changes when the screen gets smaller */
}

@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
        /* And even smaller */
    }
```

**Part 2: For your particular custom navigation for any device who's width is 360px or less:**

You could include that as a separate max-width query, IF thats the only exception to the rule. OR use that style as your baseline, then change it for wider screens.

If you do an exception (which isn't really following mobile-first design methods), it'd be  something like:

```
body {
        /* default styles here, 
           targets mobile first
           ALSO will cover 361 - 479 width */
    }

@media screen and (max-width:360px) {
    /* style ONLY for screens with 360px or less width */
}

@media screen and (min-width:480px) {
    /* style changes when the screen gets larger */
}
etc...
```

Answer (score 19):

In short, min-width is a mobile 1st approach, max-width is a desktop 1st approach.

Min-width is the minimum width at which a style will START to be applied. (Have to be ordered from smallest to largest to work properly, regular styles first). Put another way: If device width is greater than or equal to..., then apply some specific styles. With min-width, styles START and continue forever as long as min-width is met, and no max-width is specified.

Max-width is the maximum width at which a style will continue to be applied. After that, the style will STOP being applied. (Have to be ordered from largest to smallest to work properly, regular styles first). Put another way: If device width is less than or equal to..., then apply specific styles. Styles STOP as soon as width greater than max-width is hit.

Finally, It depends on how you want to implement. There is no ONE RIGHT solution as some may claim. In my opinion min-width works great when starting from scratch, but max-width often makes more sense to me when retrofitting an existing web site.

Answer (score 10):

**What are Mobile-first and Desktop-first approaches?**

A ***mobile-first*** approach to styling means that styles are applied first to mobile devices. Advanced styles and other overrides for larger screens are then added into the stylesheet via media queries.

This approach uses

> min-width

media queries.

**Here’s a quick example:**

```
// This applies from 0px to 600px
body {
  background: red;
}

// This applies from 600px onwards
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background: green;
  }
}
```

In the example above,  will have a red background below 600px. Its background changes to green at 600px and beyond.

On the flipside, a **desktop-first** approach to styling means that styles are applied first to desktop devices. Advanced styles and overrides for smaller screens are then added into the stylesheet via media queries.
This approach uses >max-width 
media queries.

**Here’s a quick example:**

```
// This applies from 600px onwards
body {
  background: green;
}

// This applies from 0px to 600px
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

will have a background colour of green for all widths. If the screen goes below 600px, the background colour becomes red instead.

Answer (score 7):

Because you're developing a website starting with a mobile design and increasing complexity with resolution, I would advise going with `min-width` because that follows the same work pattern.

Technically, `min-width` is "mobile first" in the sense that you generally begin developing for mobile and add more complexity as the resolution increases.

However, the term gained popularity more so over its alternative meaning which has generally come to imply more about an increase of focus on mobile efforts and prioritization (mostly fueled by clients or management that don't understand the technical inference). That is likely why you end up seeing a lot of `min-width` examples online (trendy bloggers writing about trendy topics).

When I work with complex desktop designs, I personally find it easier to write `max-width` queries to "simplify the equation" so-to-speak. But using `max-width` queries does not prevent you from focusing on mobile and can still completely be a part of a "mobile first" strategy.

In either case, the most important thing is consistency. Use one and stick to it for that project. A project can become very confusing if it uses both.

As a final note, using less queries when possible is ideal. This can be achieved through good responsive design.

Comment: Agree. Though I like mobile first, but when trying to change from `max-width` to `min-width`, I hate the *leak* feature that hard to specify style for lager screens

Answer (score 3):

I had a unresponsive website first, designed for desktops. Then added responsiveness by adding max-width media queries.

My site now has layouts for 320px, 480px, 768px, 960px, and 1024px etc. wide devices, and so I have added media queries that look like `max-width: 479px`, `max-width: 767px`, `max-width: 959px` etc. This works fine - the site behaves as it should.

However, I've recently found that the Chrome Developer Tools "Device Mode" has a Media Queries Tool that is really, really useful to me. It allows me to click to display the website at each media query level that Chrome finds on my page. This is a great help to me when designing the responsive layouts.

The Media Queries Tool uses the numbers it finds in the media queries, i.e. 479, 767, 959, 1023 etc. But this means that, for example, if I want to see what how my layout for a 480px-wide device looks, I have to click the max-width 767px level media query, which to me is quite unintuitive.

This has made me rethink my current desktop-first CSS, and I will be rewriting my CSS using a mobile-first approach.

I think the mobile-first CSS using `min-width` will be much more readable, because you will see a media query for `min-width: 480px` and know that will be the CSS for a 480px-wide device.

Answer (score 1):

The majority of sites I've been working on are designed for desktop first and in these cases using `max-width` queries makes sense. Generally if you are starting small screen first use `min-width` and then build on top with media queries targeting larger resolutions.

You can of course mix both min and max queries to get specific resolutions

Maybe have a look at using `min-device-width` for the specific issue you're having with the navigation

Comment: I dare say that in 2013 the reason why the design was "desktop first" was because it was an existing (desktop) design that was being made responsive for mobile?