# media query does not switch below 768 when resize window

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, responsiveness

```
@media(min-width:768px){body:border:1px solid red;}
```

if i resize the window below 768px , it does not switch to iphone6+ media query

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-width: 736px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: landscape) { body:border:1px solid red;}
```

Please suggest

Comment: do you re-size or you use the toggle device mode???

Comment: please use only 

@media screen(max-width:768px){...}

Answer (score 1):

Min-width is the minimum width so anything *above* 768px. If you are wanting to have something effect 768px AND below it's `@media screen(max-width:768px){...}`

[Max-Width vs Min-Width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647380/max-width-vs-min-width)