# Setting max-width and min-width at the same time

Tags: html, css, frontend

Can I set min-width and max-width at the same time? Is this acceptable?
It is for my task for course but I don't know that is this okay projects.I didn't try it.

I don't know that is this okay for real projects? Like is this okay for developers?

Comment: Of course you can. Why would you think they can't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly acceptable to set both `min-width` and `max-width` properties on an element in CSS. In fact, it's a common practice in web development, especially for creating responsive layouts.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.box {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      This is a box with min-width and max-width.
    </div>
  </div>
```

In this example, we have a .box element within a .container. The .box element has a minimum width of `200px` and a maximum width of `400px`.

for more best concept vist MDN Web Docs: [max width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width)  ......    [min width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set both. This is usually used in responsive design so the content works both in small devices such as smartphones and big screen devices such as desktops, I really don't see a problem.

Take a look at the w3schools explanations:
[max-width](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.php)
[min-width](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.php)

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647380/max-width-vs-min-width) if you want to learn more about their use in media queries.